# React componentWillReceiveProps not updating state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lifecycle

I've got this React parent component here. The children components at this point are just returning dropdown menus. I expected that componentWillReceiveProps would update the state here, which in turn should be passed to StopList as props. However, when state.selectedSub is changed through handleSubSelect, nothing happens and StopList doesn't receive any props.

Is my mistake with the asynchronous nature of componentWillReceiveProps? Is it in the wrong place in my code? Am I using the wrong lifecycle method?

```
// We're controlling all of our state here and using children
// components only to return lists and handle AJAX calls.

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SubList from './SubList';
import StopList from './StopList';

class SubCheck extends Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        selectedSub: '--',
        selectedStop: null,
        stops: ['--'],
    };
    this.handleSubSelect.bind(this);
    this.handleStopSelect.bind(this);
    }

    // We want the user to be able to select their specific subway
    // stop, so obviously a different array of stops needs to be 
    // loaded for each subway. We're getting those from utils/stops.json.
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        var stopData = require('../utils/stops');
        var stopsArray = [];
        var newSub = nextProps.selectedSub
        for(var i = 0; i < stopData.length; i++) {
            var stop = stopData[i];

            if (stop.stop_id.charAt(0) === this.state.selectedSub) {
                stopsArray.push(stop.stop_name);
            }
        }
        if (stopsArray.length !== 0 && newSub !== this.state.selectedSub) {
            this.setState({stops: stopsArray});
        }
    }

    handleSubSelect(event) {
        this.setState({selectedSub:event.target.selectedSub});
    }

    handleStopSelect(event) {
        this.setState({selectedStop:event.target.selectedStop})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <SubList onSubSelect={this.handleSubSelect.bind(this)}/>
                <StopList stops={this.state.stops} onStopSelect={this.handleStopSelect.bind(this)}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SubCheck;
```

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` is called when props passed from the parent is changed. It wont be called when you call `setState` like you are doiing in `handleSubSelect`

Comment: @Prakashsharma So I can't use it in my child component and also keep that child a stateless functional component?

Comment: You want to run `componentWillReceiveProps` code when `handleSubSelect` is called, right??

Comment: @Prakashsharma Correct. I may need to use something other than componentWillReceiveProps - I'm not sure. What I want is to change the state (and therefore give different props to the StopList child component) when handleSubSelect is called. I also was attempting to keep all of my child components stateless and have state live only in the parent component.

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` is not gonna help in this case. You can put logic of `componentWillReceiveProps` inside `handleSubSelect` method itself. Is there any reason you are not doing that?

Comment: No there wasn't a reason - just thought I was supposed to be using lifecycle methods here. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are duplicating data, and causing yourself headaches that aren't necessary.

Both `selectedSub` and `selectedStop` are being stored as `props` and as `state` attributes.  You need to decide where this data lives and put it in a singular location.

The problem you are encountering entirely revolves round the fact that you are changing the `state` attribute and expecting this to trigger a change to your props.  Just because they share a name does not mean they are the same value.

Comment: This seems like an extremely helpful answer, but can you elaborate? I appreciate you bearing with me, as I'm 100% self taught and learn by making mistakes like this. I understand what you're saying about storing those identifiers as both props and state, but shouldn't I be setting the state and then passing it to the child components as props?

Comment: Yes, storing as state and then passing as props is 100% correct.  The problem is that, within the same component you do: `this.setState({selectedSub: ...})` and also `nextProps.selectedSub`.  This implies that you are expecting to set this value within the state, but also retrieve it from the props ***of the same component***, not passed to a child as you imply.  You probably want to move all of the code in `componentWillReceiveProps` into the `handleSubSelect` method, and reference `state.selectedSub` only, rather than `props.selectedSub`.

Comment: Ohhh yeah that makes sense. I actually was not under the assumption that nextProps.selectedSub would work and had it in there as a placeholder (which I foolishly forgot to comment in the code I posted here).